# How can I see the list of available merge tools for git on the command line?

Tags: linux, git, mergetool

I am using git on a virtual machine Ubuntu server running command-line only and I don't know vim (and frankly I don't really want to learn it right now) so I don't want to use vimdiff. How can I get the list of available merge tools for git?

Bonus points for a list of merge tools usable from the command line that don't have too much of a steep learning curve!

Comment: Doesn't your host OS permit you to read the documentation?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147681/command-line-merge-conflict-tools

Comment: @devnull: you're right, I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run it without a tool value:

```
$ git mergetool --tool=
merge tool candidates: meld opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff tortoisemerge gvimdiff diffuse ecmerge p4merge araxis bc3 vimdiff emerge
```

I'll leave the bonus points for the documentation :/

Comment: Running this command also starts the merge. Is there no way to see the available list without merging? Not that it's a big bother.

Comment: `git help config` and search for mergetool - the same list is in the manual page. That won't start the merge...

Answer (score 32):

This gives you the list without actually starting the merge :

```
git mergetool --tool-help
```